# Android set listview addapter null exception

Tags: android, exception, listview, null

I need to find a way to set ListView addapter to null.The reason I want to do that is that I have 4 child activities in Tab and each one of these activities are lazy loading lists.In OnDestroy method of the activity I do this :

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    adapter.imageLoader.stopThread();
    listView.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

But when I do this I get this exception :

```
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.stampii.stampii/com.stampii.stampii.mystampii.OwnedStampii}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3874)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3784)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.performDestroy(LocalActivityManager.java:355)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.destroyActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:381)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at com.stampii.stampii.TabGroupActivity.finishFromChild(TabGroupActivity.java:46)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.app.Activity.finish(Activity.java:3290)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at com.stampii.stampii.mystampii.OwnedStampii$1.onClick(OwnedStampii.java:38)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at com.stampii.stampii.mystampii.OwnedStampii.onDestroy(OwnedStampii.java:102)
08-13 15:29:43.115: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3861)
```

at line 102 I have this : `listView.setAdapter(null);`

If I remove that code I get :

```
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:329)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:443)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at com.stampii.stampii.tableview.ImageLoader$PhotosQueue.Clean(ImageLoader.java:126)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at com.stampii.stampii.tableview.ImageLoader.queuePhoto(ImageLoader.java:59)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at com.stampii.stampii.tableview.ImageLoader.DisplayImage(ImageLoader.java:51)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at com.stampii.stampii.tableview.LazyAdapter.getView(LazyAdapter.java:62)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:521)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:805)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-13 15:33:36.545: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10511):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is ImageLoader.class :

```
package com.stampii.stampii.tableview;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import com.stampii.stampii.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader extends Activity {

    //the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    private File cacheDir;
    private AssetManager mAssetManager;


    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);
        mAssetManager = context.getAssets();

        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }


    final int stub_id=R.drawable.default_img;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        if(cache.containsKey(url))
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String src) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;


                //Decryption
                try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
                SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("01234567890abcde".getBytes(), "AES");
                IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec("fedcba9876543210".getBytes());
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

                InputStream input = mAssetManager.open(src);
                CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(input, cipher);

                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cis);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("ERROR","Error : "+e);
                }


                return myBitmap;


        }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        Object tag=photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                        if(tag!=null && ((String)tag).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        //clear memory cache

        long size=0;
            cache.clear();

            //clear SD cache
            File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
            for(File f:files){
                size=size+f.length();
                    f.delete();
            }
}




}
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign `null` as the adapter. Thats not a valid one and will of course throw a `NullPointerException` to emphasize this.

*The other exception is hard to tell with that small piece of code. Please post some more.*

Comment: Not 100% sure, but as far as I can see you don't have a `onCreate()` function or anything where you set the layout (via `setContentView()`) for this activity. But you have to set one. What the exception basically tells you is that the listview can't measure how big it should be, since it can't determine the size of other UI components and how much space they consume. Because there are none.

Comment: Actually it's not an activity and I forgot to delete extends Activity,that'w why I don't have onCreate method.And basically the second exception I get everytime when I;m changing like 20 or 30 times between 4 activities which has lazy list.After i remove extends Activity,I didn't get that.So for now it's ok.Thanks for the notice.And how can I set the listview size?

Comment: Usually the best way is setting it in your XML layout via the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes. It should be possible in code too, but that gets ugly really fast in my experience.

Comment: Actually these parameters are set for the listview.

Comment: Thats fine, just wanted to point out thats the best place to change the size. I believe you have to set these in the first place.